# Figure out php user without shell access

Tags: php, users

Is there a way to figure out which user it is that executes a php-script in a webserver using php-commands? (I don't have shell access to the server running httpd, so I cant use `ps`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function [posix_getuid](http://www.php.net/manual/function.posix-getuid.php).

Comment: Thanks. That was the key-idea. In the end I used `print_r(posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid()));`